# Does holistic health have its roots in Nietzsche's philosophy?

Tags: nietzsche, psychology, psychoanalysis

Was the Nietzsche's work the main influential thing in how people thought about holistic health as both our mental and physical health? Could it be that it was the Nietzsche's *Human all too human* that had brought people about to "enhance" their psychology with things like yoga or psychologists meetings  and to jog/exercise on a daily basis?

Comment: I do not think so... [Nietzsche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrich_Nietzsche#Psychological_illness_and_death_.281889.E2.80.931900.29) since his childhood, various disruptive illnesses had plagued him, including moments of shortsightedness that left him nearly blind, migraine headaches, and violent indigestion. He may have contracted syphilis, in 1889, suffered a mental collapse, was brought to a psychiatric clinic. 1/2

Comment: In 1898 and 1899 Nietzsche suffered at least two strokes. This partially paralyzed him, leaving him unable to speak or walk. He likely suffered from clinical hemiparesis/hemiplegia on the left side of his body by 1899. After contracting pneumonia in mid-August 1900, he had another stroke during the night of 24–25 August and died on 25 August. Not exactly a champion of "holistic health" (assuming that it has some meaning ...) 2/2

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, the documentary greatly reflects how had his health problems projected in his life philosophy - partially because he had realized that his health was so bad because of his depressions linked to his overall life approach.

Comment: "*[The origins of yoga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoga) have been speculated to date back to pre-Vedic Indian traditions, it is mentioned in the Rigveda, but most likely developed around the sixth and fifth centuries BCE*", that would be over 2000 years before Nietzsche. Nietzsche's philosophical "mentor", [Schopenhauer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Schopenhauer), was into Indian philosophy and its "psychic" focus, which could influence young Nietzsche. So no, it did not come from him, but his popularity [might have helped promote it](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7728371).

Comment: @Conifold That's obviously what I meantt

Comment: In that case I suspect that clinical psychiatrists promoting Oriental philosophy, like Jung, had more to do with it than Nietzsche. Also the idea of all-fit person, "sound mind in a sound body", was an ideal in ancient Greece (attributed as far back as Thales), turned into a Latin proverb ([mens sana in corpore sano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mens_sana_in_corpore_sano)) by Romans, made prominent again during the Renaissence, and institutionalized in classical education long before Nietzsche.

Comment: @Conifold Yes, thanks, I've heard about those appearances but they seem not to resemble the actual physical exercise and absolutely not the "psychoanalytic" (I mean, again, the "mental health" concept) approach to personhood.